# Parsing XML: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, xml

I'm currently having difficulty parsing an XML.

the data of my `Output.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file>
  <ALL_INSTANCES>
    <instance>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <start>0</start>
      <end>17.96</end>
      <code>14. Jordan Brian Henderson</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
      <pos_y>34.0</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>8</ID>
      <start>10.28</start>
      <end>30.28</end>
      <code>26. Andrew Robertson</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>61.7</pos_x>
      <pos_y>68.0</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>1321</ID>
      <start>3770.67</start>
      <end>3790.67</end>
      <code>3. Fabinho</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>2nd half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>62.7</pos_x>
      <pos_y>3.7</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>1882</ID>
      <start>5695.17</start>
      <end>5715.17</end>
      <code>2. Fabio Cardoso</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Porto</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Interceptions</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>2nd half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>8.1</pos_x>
      <pos_y>46.3</pos_y>
    </instance>
  </ALL_INSTANCES>
</file>
```

the code I am running is

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
cols = ["ID", "Start", "End", "Player", "Team", "Action","Half","x","y"]
rows = []
  
# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse = Xet.parse('Output.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()
for i in root:
    ID = i.find("ID").text
    Start = i.find("start").text
    End = i.find("end").text
    Player= i.find("code").text
    Team = i.findall("./label[1]/text")[0].text
    Action = i.findall("./label[2]/text")[0].text
    Half = i.findall("./label[3]/text")[0].text
    x = i.find("pos_x").text
    y = i.find("pos_y").text
  
    rows.append({"ID": ID,
                 "Start": Start,
                 "End": End,
                 "Player": Player,
                 "Team": Team,
                 "Action": Action,
                 "Half": Half,
                 "x": x,
                 "y": y})
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
  
# Writing dataframe to csv
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

but I'm getting the error of

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-256-f9c125ff9538> in <module>
      7 root = xmlparse.getroot()
      8 for i in root:
----> 9     ID = i.find("ID").text
     10     Start = i.find("start").text
     11     End = i.find("end").text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-256-f9c125ff9538> in <module>
      7 root = xmlparse.getroot()
      8 for i in root:
----> 9     ID = i.find("ID").text
     10     Start = i.find("start").text
     11     End = i.find("end").text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I understand the error, but I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

Comment: When you do `for i in root:`, which tags do you expect `i` to refer to? Do those tags contain an `ID` child? How many times do you think that loop will run? How many times does it run, and which tags does it say it's looking at (hint: `print(i)`)?

Comment: I'm hoping it would retrieve the tags from under ```instance``` tags, but running ```print(i)```  actually says it's looking at ```ALL_INSTANCES```

Comment: Well, yes, because your XML root is the `file` tag, which contains just that one `ALL_INSTANCES` child. Understanding this, do you see how to solve the problem?

Comment: So what I’ve done is add as an example ID = i.find(‘instance/ID’).text too all of them. But it’s just grabbing the first instance.

Comment: Which is the tag that you want the `for i in root:` loop to iterate over? How do you get *that* tag?

Comment: So I went for ```for i in root.findall('.//instance'):``` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try and take it from here:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file>
  <ALL_INSTANCES>
    <instance>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <start>0</start>
      <end>17.96</end>
      <code>14. Jordan Brian Henderson</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
      <pos_y>34.0</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>8</ID>
      <start>10.28</start>
      <end>30.28</end>
      <code>26. Andrew Robertson</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>61.7</pos_x>
      <pos_y>68.0</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>1321</ID>
      <start>3770.67</start>
      <end>3790.67</end>
      <code>3. Fabinho</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>2nd half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>62.7</pos_x>
      <pos_y>3.7</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>1882</ID>
      <start>5695.17</start>
      <end>5715.17</end>
      <code>2. Fabio Cardoso</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Porto</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Interceptions</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>2nd half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>8.1</pos_x>
      <pos_y>46.3</pos_y>
    </instance>
  </ALL_INSTANCES>
</file>'''

fields = ['ID','start','end','code','pos_x','pos_y']

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = []
for inst in root.findall('.//instance'):
    data.append({f:inst.find(f).text for f in fields})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

output

```
     ID    start      end                        code pos_x pos_y
0     1        0    17.96  14. Jordan Brian Henderson  52.4  34.0
1     8    10.28    30.28        26. Andrew Robertson  61.7  68.0
2  1321  3770.67  3790.67                  3. Fabinho  62.7   3.7
3  1882  5695.17  5715.17            2. Fabio Cardoso   8.1  46.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems all children of `instance` elements are needed so they can be handled sequentially according to the xml sample.

Using XPath to find all `instance` elements and iterating over them

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('/home/lmc/tmp/tmp.xml')
cols = ["ID", "Start", "End", "Player", "Team", "Action","Half","x","y"]
xcols = ["ID", "start", "end", "code", "label", "label","label","pos_x","pos_y"]
root = tree.getroot()
steps = tree.xpath('//instance')
for s in steps:
    row= dict()
    x=0
    for i in s:
        if xcols[x] != 'label':
            row[cols[x]] = i.text
        else:
            t = i.find('./text')
            row[cols[x]] = t.text
        x+=1
    print(row)
```

Result:

```
{'ID': '1', 'Start': '0', 'End': '17.96', 'Player': '14. Jordan Brian Henderson', 'Team': 'Liverpool FC', 'Action': 'Passes accurate', 'Half': '1st half', 'x': '52.4', 'y': '34.0'}
{'ID': '8', 'Start': '10.28', 'End': '30.28', 'Player': '26. Andrew Robertson', 'Team': 'Liverpool FC', 'Action': 'Passes accurate', 'Half': '1st half', 'x': '61.7', 'y': '68.0'}
{'ID': '1321', 'Start': '3770.67', 'End': '3790.67', 'Player': '3. Fabinho', 'Team': 'Liverpool FC', 'Action': 'Passes accurate', 'Half': '2nd half', 'x': '62.7', 'y': '3.7'}
{'ID': '1882', 'Start': '5695.17', 'End': '5715.17', 'Player': '2. Fabio Cardoso', 'Team': 'Porto', 'Action': 'Interceptions', 'Half': '2nd half', 'x': '8.1', 'y': '46.3'}
```